# plt.show() freezes after using plt.close('all') when calling from tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

The code is supposed to wait for user click, then it will close the plot and continue. This works great when not done from the tkinter loop, but if the plot function is invoked from tkinter, the program freezes until the tkinter window is closed.

So if you run this code, you will get a plot, then when you click on the plot, the plot will close, and program will display "Hello from: main program" which is what I want, but then, the tkinter window opens with a button. When you click the button, the plot will show again, but this time when you click inside the plot, the plot will close, but no text will be shown. Once you close the tkinter window, the text will display "hello from: tkinter."

This is not what I want, I want the text to display as soon as I click on the plot like on the first example. Can someone provide any guidance?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class patito():
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
        self.y = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1]

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.plot_this(location)
        

    def select_peak(self,event):
        plt.close("all")# close plot and continue to print("hello from:")

    def plot_this(self, location):
        plt.plot(self.x,self.y)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.select_peak)#call select_peak when clicking inside plot
        plt.show()
        print("hello from: " + location)

def call_patito(location):
    x = patito(location)

def tkinter_call_patito():
    x = patito("tkinter")
########################### Program starts Here ##############
    
call_patito("main program")
             
root = tk.Tk()
main_frame = Frame(root)
title_frame = Frame(root)

source_button =      Button(title_frame,justify=LEFT, text='Create patito object', command = tkinter_call_patito).grid(row=1, column = 1)
title_frame.pack()
main_frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I got `hello from: tkinter` just after clicking the plot.

Comment: that's odd. On my PC I have to close the tkinter window to see "hello from: tkinter." are you running this on windows?

Comment: Yes Python 3.9.1 in Windows 10.

Comment: Agh, this is killing me. I updated to 3.9.1 and still same issue. I get hello from: main program when I click on the first plot, but when the plot gets called from the tkinter window (after i click on the button), the text "hello from: tkinter" does not show until after I close the tkinter window

Comment: Ah, looks like I got it fixed by using the Qt5Agg backend for matplotlib. I tried WxAgg but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, looks like I got it fixed by using the Qt5Agg backend for matplotlib. I tried WxAgg but didn't work for me.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
```